# Couchdb https/ssl works locally but times out when I try to connect from a remote client

Tags: curl, ssl, https, couchdb

Using Couchdb 1.5, I have followed these instructions:

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.5.x/config/http.html#config-ssl

and everything works locally :)

When I use curl to connect from a remote system http works fine, but curl -k https... times out :(

I am using a self-signed cert.

Comment: Are you sure that CouchDB listens public IP? And firewall accepts incoming connections to it and related port?

Comment: I'm having almost the same issue. Localhost works fine, but when I try connecting remotely I'm getting a `curl: (35) Server aborted the SSL handshake`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timeout means that the connection was not rejected, but was dropped. It could be due to host was not found or firewall dropped the incoming connection.

Try to ping your server to ensure that there are no routing issues.

If ping works fine, than try to disable your firewall temporary.

Concrete steps depends on your operating system, so I'm not providing exact commands.